# How to convert ambiguous grammar to unambiguous grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, ambiguous-grammar

I've got a grammar which I believe is ambiguous. I don't know how to eliminate the ambiguity and convert it to an unambiguous grammar.

```
expr    ::= num | lvalue | incrop expr | expr incrop | expr binop expr | (expr)

lvalue  ::= $expr

incrop  ::= ++ | --

binop   ::= + | - |

num ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

And This is what I came up with:

```
expr ::=    num expr' | lvalue expr'| incrop expr expr' | (expr) expr'

expr' ::= incrop expr' | binop expr expr' | empty

lvalue  ::= $expr

incrop  ::= ++ | --

binop   ::= + | - |

num ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

is it correct?

Comment: I think as written, the grammar could only be satisfied by an infinite sequence of paired plus or minus characters, since the first token of an `S` must be `++` or `--`, and it must be followed by an `S` (which is in turn a `++` or `--` followed by an `S`, ad infinitum).

Comment: @supercat It is not the whole grammar. This is the part which makes it ambiguous.

Comment: That part does not in and of itself make it ambiguous since `S` has no finite expansion and thus the only relevant expansion is `AS`.  What is necessary to make it unambiguous would depend upon what else exists that makes it ambiguous.

Comment: @supercat I just modified the grammar. This is the actual grammar

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54558463/1566221), which tries to explain how to write a  grammar which doesn't have these ambiguities.